# How a UINavigationController becomes navigationController of a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

When I initialize a UINavigationController by passing a UITableViewController as its root view controller, I can obtain the UINavigationController by UITableViewController property 'navigationController'. I'm wondering:

1. is such property set automatically during initialization?
2. is navigationController a property of some protocol that UITableViewController or its parent class implements?

Comment: Doesn't matter and may change.

Comment: Do you mean `UINavigationController` instead of `UINavigationBar`? And `navigationController` instead of `navigationBar`?

Comment: There's seem to be a lot of confusion here... UINavigationBar doesn't have a root view controller. UITableView is not a view controller... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And do you mean `UITableViewController` instead of `UITableView`?

Comment: Show the code so that we are not confusing down in the comments :P

Comment: Sorry guys, post it when a bit drunk, have revised class names ^_^

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` calls `[rootViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self]`

From this method viewcontrollers know where they have been added.

Also viewcontrollers have getter `parentViewController`.
`navigationController` is just convenience getter, that cast `parentViewController` into `UINavigationController *`.